# determine current python installation parent path, python folder name, and full path

Tags: python, path, installation, cross-platform, instance

on windows sys.prefix is the python folder, but linux it points to /usr generally which now means a directory hunt by name must occur unless there is another way.

Is there?

Relying on the folder name is chaotic too, 'Python27', 'python2.7' just to name the frequent ones.

Is this script overkill? Am I doing this right?

os.environ can't help because there may not be a PYTHON_PATH, or whats running may not match

sys.executable can't help because it would only be right on windows.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
# rev 0.0.0.1
import os, platform, sys
"""File: _python_pfn.py
Seems excessive...
3 imports, 3 functions, 30 lines just to 
determine current python installation parent path, python folder name, and full path
"""
def _python_parent():
    """assume linux, but if windows just return sys.prefix"""
    ret = os.path.join('{}'.format(sys.prefix), 'lib')
    if platform.uname()[0] == 'Windows':
        ret = '{}'.format(sys.prefix)
    return ret

def _python_name(path):#, major=None, minor=None
    """assume windows, but if not listdir and find"""
    ma, mi = (str(sys.version_info[0]), str(sys.version_info[1]))
    #if major is not None: ma = str(major)
    #if minor is not None: ma = str(minor)
    ret = os.path.split(path)[1]
    if platform.uname()[0] != 'Windows':
        ls = [k for k in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, k)) ]
        for k in ls:
            if k.lower().find('python') != -1:
                if k.find(ma) != -1:
                    if k.find(mi) != -1:
                        ret = k
    return ret

def _python_path(path):
    """use as _python_path(_python_parent())"""
    return os.path.join(path, _python_name(path))
```

Comment: Aside: why do you want to know this?  Does `distutils`/`distutils2` not work for your use case?

Comment: Are you looking for `sys.exec_prefix` and/or `sys.executable`?

Comment: @mgilson I thought that and `sys.executable` maybe...

Comment: @JonClements -- Yeah, I was finishing my comment as you were typing yours :).

Answer (score 3):

Isn't it enough to get the path

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.dirname(os.__file__)
'/usr/lib/python2.7'
```

Comment: will that always return the python install directory on all/any os?

Comment: sys.exec_prefix return /usr for me

Comment: sys.executable return /usr/bin/python

Comment: @Brian Cain - to retrieve the current running python installation path and siblings if desired of coarse.

Comment: @user1576916 I think it should return because where else os module can be installed?